# RAC() and .rac_command are not working together

Tags: reactive-cocoa

So I have a UIBarButtonItem in my navigation bar and want to use RAC() like this:

```
RAC(myButton, enabled) = [RACSignal 
  combineLatest:@[ RACObserve(self, password), RACObserve(self, passwordConfirmation) ] 
  reduce:^(NSString *password, NSString *passwordConfirm) {
    return @([passwordConfirm isEqualToString:password]);
  }];
```

But also [rac_command](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/fd533d07b64d40cf79d069584d8cd95158998095/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/UIButton+RACCommandSupport.m#L22) to catch when tapped, like this:

```
myButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
  // Do stuff
  return [RACSignal empty];
}];
```

When I combine those two, I get an assertion error.

So the question is: How can I use RAC() and rac_command in combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-[RACCommand initWithEnabled:signalBlock:]` instead.

Comment: I found this too (after I posted the question). I will try it in about an hour and mark your answer as accepted - thanks!